# How to add weekdays with year and month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, dayofweek

I am trying to do create a column that has a year, month, weekdays in the **dateformat**

[image]

like **2020-10-Thu** or **2020-10-04** but tha both data will be in date format ther is any way to do that thing

Comment: what is the issue you are running in to

Comment: why do you post a screenshot instead of text? what is "dateformat", do you mean datetime data type? what did you try?

Comment: I am trying to create a DateTime format with week but if use strftime and something else it converts this date-time into a string 2020-10-Thu i need it should be in date format there is anyway to do this @MrFuppes

Comment: Ok could you please clarify, what does WOD mean?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to have a column that contains the date in the format of **2020-10-Thu** or **2020-10-04**? If that's the case, the code below should work for you (Just note that the `First Format` and `Second Format` columns end up being of type string, also note that the weekdays begin with 1 where sunday is labelled as 0).

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

originalDates = pd.date_range(start="2020-02-02",end="2020-03-03")
firstFormat = pd.Series([datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%a') for x in originalDates])
secondFormat = pd.Series([datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%w') for x in originalDates])

frame = {'Original Dates': originalDates, 'First Format': firstFormat, 'Second Format': secondFormat}

df = pd.DataFrame(frame)
```

The df variable ends up looking like this:

| Original Dates | First Format | Second Format |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-03 | 2020-02-Mon | 2020-02-1 |
| 2020-02-04 | 2020-02-Tue | 2020-02-2 |
| 2020-02-05 | 2020-02-Wed | 2020-02-3 |

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but I'm not aware of it at this time.

Comment: hey thanks for your solution and your effort I appreciate it but that data is in string format  i need that data in date format there is any way

Comment: @Noman Sorry, unfortunately I don't know how to do that. I have tried converting the resulting strings to datetime objects with the strptime() function, but that reverts the day part of the date back into the day of the month format.